# Laravel High CPU usage php-fpm

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, fpm

I created a test api that gets data from cache/redis, when I run domain/api/test it consumed up to 15% cpu

```
//api: laravel 8.54
**1** -> cpu ~10%
Route::get('test', function(){
    return \Cache::remember('test', 6666, function () {
        return \App\Models\ActivityLog::where('id','<',3355)
               ->paginate(20, ['*'], 'page', 2)
               ->toJson();
    });
});
**2** -> 9%cpu
Route::get('test', function(){
    return "string";
});
```

vps : 2 CPU 2 Physical core 2 logical core

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+    COMMAND                                                                   
     www       20   0                       S  10.7  3.6     0:49.75  php-fpm
```

```
PHP-fpm config:
pm = dynamic
pm.status_path = /phpfpm_74_status
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 30
```

I've executed: run cmd php artisan optimize, optimize autoload, debug false, appenv production, install opcache, apcu.

This is an old problem and of course i have referred to few posts but why just such a piece of code consumes so much cpu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and how much rows does the ``activity_logs`` table contains? Also migration code for the table

Comment: maybe you can trying setting up a profiler (for example php-spx-profiler) https://github.com/MedUnes/php-spx-installer and then see which functions consume most of your CPU based on flame graphs. otherwise you can use tools like the StopWatch component https://github.com/symfony/stopwatch to profile line by line suspicious calls

Comment: Sorry for possibly causing misunderstanding, i mean even if it only returns a string to api test, it still takes up to 10% cpu ~ 10requests to the test api also leads to full cpu. Cache::remember is just a side question because although it only takes up 1% of the cpu, it will become a big problem later. My ActivityLog model code returns not too much because it is limited so I will Update and remove ActivityLog related results to avoid lengthy post.

Comment: I tried reading through those two packages and it seems like they are used to display information of a piece of code (time, % cpu...)